# Keep all the column values from first row and any updates in subsequent rows in a Pandas group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe with an `id` column, a date column `dt` and a few binary columns that could contain 0 or 1 (or no values at all).

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
  
# initialize list of lists 
data = [
    ['A', None, None, 0, 0, datetime.date(2020,5,1)],
    ['A', 1, None, 0, 1, datetime.date(2020,5,2)],
    ['A', None, 1, 0, 0, datetime.date(2020,5,3)],
    ['B', 1, 1, 0, None, datetime.date(2020,5,3)]
] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'dt']) 
  
# print dataframe. 
df

   id   d1   d2  d3   d4          dt
0   A  NaN  NaN   0  0.0  2020-05-01
1   A  1.0  NaN   0  1.0  2020-05-02
2   A  NaN  1.0   0  0.0  2020-05-03
3   B  1.0  1.0   0  NaN  2020-05-03
```

For each ID, on any given date, I want to track changes in the binary columns from the earliest date until the most recent date, keeping the latest value but **ignoring any changes from a number to None**.

There will be one row for each ID showing the latest known values.

To clarify, for each ID, going row by row from earliest date to the most recent date:

- If column value changes from None to a number, use number as the latest known value
- If column value changes from 0 to 1, use 1 as the latest known value
- If column value changes from 1 to 0, use 0 as the latest known value
- However, if a column changes from a number to None, keep the number as the latest known value

For example, in the dataframe above, for `id ='A'`:

On 2 May 2020, the value will be `'A', 1, None, 0, 1` (because `d1` changes from None to 1, `d4` changes from 0 to 1)

On 3 May 2020, the value will be `'A', 1, 1, 0, 0` (because `d2` changes from None to 1 and `d4` changes from 1 to 0, however `d1` changes from 1 to None so still keep 1 instead of None because that's the last known value)

I am a bit lost on how to track changes like this. Is there any way I can apply `shift` in the lambda or do I write a custom function to do these row by row comparisons?

`df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='dt'). ???)`

**Edited to add**: In the end, I just want one dataframe with one row for each ID and the latest known values for all binary columns.

```
    id  d1   d2  d3   d4
0   A   1    1   0    0
1   B   1    1   0    NaN
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what the criteria are for the decision, so I can't respond to that, but it's easy to make it a vertical holding record It is. Is that all I have to say to you?

Comment: @r-beginners the criteria is fairly simple - for each group (by ID), I have to compare each row with the previous row.. so I start from 1 May, initialize each of `d1, d2, d3, d4`; then on 2 May, compare values of these columns with the previous row i.e. May 1, if anything has changed to a number, I use the new value otherwise keep the same; then do the same thing for 3 May, comparing with already known values, and so on.. I only update if the value in the column has changed to a number (so null to 0 or 1 is okay.. 0 to 1 and vice versa is okay.. but if a number changes to null, then no update)

Comment: I wrote the code again in response to the comments, but there was a decision logic in one place that could not be improved, and the It is. I will still post if you want to. I'm sorry I can't help you.

Comment: No problem, @r-beginners - I appreciate your patience with me and the effort to help :) I figured out a solution and posted it below in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to figure out the solution to my problem - [pandas.DataFrame.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html#pandas-dataframe-ffill)

As I mentioned in my question, I want to track the latest "known" numerical values for each column for each `id` on any given date.

So, I get what I need if I do:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='dt').ffill().tail(1))
```

This is because:

- For each ID, (such as `A` or `B`), the rows get sorted by date `dt`
- Forward-fill will make sure that null values in more recent dates will be filled by preceding numeric values.
- Numerical values remain unaffected. If I pick the latest date, the latest numerical values will be available, along with nulls that are now filled with most recent known numerical values.
- Finally, I take the row with the latest date using `tail(1)`

This gives me my desired output:

```
    id  d1   d2  d3   d4
0   A   1    1   0    0
1   B   1    1   0    NaN
```

If I wanted to look at any date before the latest date, I could simply filter and keep rows less than desired date, and do the same thing. That would give me latest known values until that date.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved the problem. I posted my approach.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to convert the sample data into a vertical format and compare it to the previous day's data by id, and I ran into a challenge when I tried to use a looping process to deal with it.

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['id','dt'], var_name='D', value_name='Value')
df.sort_values(['id','D'], ascending=[True,True], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
df
0   A   2020-05-01  d1  NaN
1   A   2020-05-02  d1  1.0
2   A   2020-05-03  d1  NaN
3   A   2020-05-01  d2  NaN
4   A   2020-05-02  d2  NaN
5   A   2020-05-03  d2  1.0
6   A   2020-05-01  d3  0.0
7   A   2020-05-02  d3  0.0
8   A   2020-05-03  d3  0.0
9   A   2020-05-01  d4  0.0
10  A   2020-05-02  d4  1.0
11  A   2020-05-03  d4  0.0
12  B   2020-05-03  d1  1.0
13  B   2020-05-03  d2  1.0
14  B   2020-05-03  d3  0.0
15  B   2020-05-03  d4  NaN

cnt = 0
for idx,d,val in zip(df.index,df['D'],df['Value']):
    if cnt == 0:
        df.at[idx, 'new'] = val
    if cnt >= 1:
        print(idx, d, pre_d, val, pre_val)
        if d == pre_d:
            if val == 0.0 or pre_val == 1.0:
                df.at[idx, 'new'] = 1.0
            if val == 1.0 or pre_val == 0.0:
                df.at[idx, 'new'] = 1.0 
　　　　　　　　（....)
        else:
            df.at[idx, 'new'] = val

    pre_idx = idx
    pre_val = val
    pre_d = d
    cnt += 1
```